# Financial Use of Word : SECURITY

Tags: origin-unknown

To be a man of better literate in Finance, learning some basic concepts regarding financial assets.

One seemingly quite confusing is, the concept of "Security"

When people think of security, it is kind of object that secures my lend (maybe). So I thought it might be a very similar concept to "collateral" but existing in a much more abstracted way.

Referenced with Wikipedia and Wiktionary, Security includes more broader sense of any tradable financial assets including stocks, treasuries, bond and any other instruments also.

Hers's the Question:

**How come the word Security so become popular and broad to contain any of these financial tradable objects?**

Any reason with fully backed industrial and historical background would be appreciate.

Comment: It is a quite old usage: Security meaning "something which secures" is from 1580s.  Legal sense of "property in bonds" is from mid-15c.; that of "document held by a creditor" is from 1680s. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=security